# Equations of motion forced by tensors with different Young structure

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, tensor-calculus, representation-theory, variational-calculus

I can't understand if varying with respect to a field with less irreducible components can force a field with more components to be zero.
In my specific situation I work in 4 dimensions and have the following term in action:
$\int d^4x C^a{ }_{nm}T_{akp}\epsilon^{nmkp}$. Here $C^a{ }_{nm}$ and $T_{akp}$ have different index symmetry:
\begin{equation}
    C^a{ }_{nm} = -C^a{ }_{mn}, C^a{ }_{na} = 0, C_{[abc]} = 0
\end{equation}
where $[ ]$ denotes antisymmetrization. While for T I only have $T_{abc} = -T_{acb}$. In other words $C_{abc}$ has the "hook" structure while $T_{abc}$ has all three irreducible components: "hook", "row" and "box". On the one hand it feels like varying w.r.t. $C_{abc}$ gives less equation of motion than there are independent components in $T_{abc}$ so these equation can't force $T_{abc}$ to vanish completely. On the other hand if I split
\begin{equation}
     T^c{ }_{ab} = \stackrel{T}{T^c{ }_{ab}} + \stackrel{A}{T^c{ }_{ab}} + \stackrel{V}{T^c{ }_{ab}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    \stackrel{A}{T^c{ }_{ab}} = \eta^{cd}T_{[dab]}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
    \stackrel{V}{T^c{ }_{ab}} = \frac{1}{3}(\delta^c{ }_b T^n{ }_{an} - \delta^c{ }_a T^n{ }_{bn})
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \stackrel{T}{T^c{ }_{ab}} = T^c{ }_{ab} - \stackrel{A}{T^c{ }_{ab}} - \stackrel{V}{T^c{ }_{ab}}
\end{equation}
substitute it in the action and vary w.r.t. $C$ I just get
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^{nmkp}T_{akp} = \epsilon^{nmkp}(\stackrel{T}{T_{akp}} + \stackrel{A}{T_{akp}} + \stackrel{V}{T_{akp}}) = 0
\end{equation}
I don't see why it should not force all these components to vanish since they are independent irreducible components and can't cancel each other. In some sense I expected the equations to look like an operator acting on $T_{abc}$ equal to zero with "extra" components being in the kernel of this operator so there are actually no conditions implied on them but I can not see that. So where am I wrong?

Comment: Hint: The $C$s are not independent: The EOMs of the $C$s do not kill the totally antisymmetric part of $T$.

Comment: @Qmechanic I know that it should be that way, I just don't understand how to show that explicitly! It should also not kill the trace part, right?